# SQL REPLACE /how to update not all data in the row/

Tags: php, sql, forms, replace

I have a table with the following columns:

```
order, host, host_price, domain, domain_price.
```

I use replace to update only the rows for domain and domain_price, not all rows.

I use this for the host:

`mysql_query("REPLACE INTO sr_orders_rel (order_id, host, host_price) VALUES ('$order_id', '$host', '$host_price')") or die (mysql_error());`

and for domain:

`mysql_query("REPLACE INTO sr_orders_rel (order_id, domain, domain_price) VALUES ('$order_id', '$domain', '$domain_price')") or die (mysql_error());`

My problem is that when first add host is writing only order, host and host_price, but when user want add and domain, don't add only rows order, domain and domain_price, but update hosts rows with empty string.

Comment: My idea is for one order only one host and one domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO sr_orders_rel(order_id, host, host_price)
    VALUES ('$order_id', '$host', '$host_price')
        on duplicate key update host = values(host), host_price = values(host_price);
```

This will keep the previous values in the row.

Comment: It's work perfectly, exactly what I'm searching for. Thanks you very much Gordon!